# Angular JS selectize error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, selectize.js

This is driving me nuts, as I can find no real reason for it.

I have an Angular 1.3.2 project.  On one view, with one controller, one factory, and 2 json files as sources.  I added 2 selectize menus, both work perfectly.

I did a save as to create a new file,  new controller, new factory, new json file.

The html I kept the same but adjusted the selectize to match the new data:

```
 <input type="text" selectize="partnerSelectMenu.options" options="partnerList" ng-model="partner.selected" />
```

The factory is

```
    app.factory('DatagroupsFactory', ['$http',
  function($http) {

    var datagroupsData;

    return {
      getDataGroups: function() {
        if (!datagroupsData) {
          datagroupsData = $http.get('scripts/data/datagroups.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
          });
        }
        return datagroupsData;
      }
    };

  }
]);
```

the controller is

```
    app.controller('AddDatagroupCtrl', function($scope, $log, PartnerFactory) {

  var partnerList = [];

  PartnerFactory.getPartners().then(function(response) {
    $scope.partnerList = response.partners;
  });

  $scope.partnerSelectMenu = {
    options: {
      valueField: 'name',
      labelField: 'name',
      searchField: ['name'],
      plugins: ['remove_button']
    }
  };

});
```

And a fragment of the json:

```
    {
  "partners" : [
    {
      "value" : "CPPRT0002706",
      "name" : "Axis Promotions"
    },
    {
      "value" : "CPPRT0005006",
      "name" : "Band of Outsiders"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the kicker:  the menu works fine, as expected, and displays my data.  The problem is I also get this error:

[image]

I have tried commenting out every part of this path of files.  Nothing.  Log debug statements show the data is correctly being passed; heck, ***the menu even works***.

The other pages on my site with selectize menus -- with the same options -- do not throw this error.  I am at a loss on how to track down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change:

```
var partnerList = [];
```

to

```
$scope.partnerList = [];
```

in your controller.

```
  app.controller('AddDatagroupCtrl', function($scope, $log, PartnerFactory) {

  $scope.partnerList = [];

  PartnerFactory.getPartners().then(function(response) {
    $scope.partnerList = response.partners;
  });

  $scope.partnerSelectMenu = {
    options: {
      valueField: 'name',
      labelField: 'name',
      searchField: ['name'],
      plugins: ['remove_button']
    }
  };
});
```

I think before your promise returns, partnerList is undefined and your  selectize is trying to get a name property from that.

Comment: Bless you!  I knew it was something stupid staring me in the face.  Most projects I do these days we use "controller as" syntax, so I was used to "var".  Thanks again.